# on iPad background won't go completely across

Tags: css, mobile-safari

Here is my code:

```
#body_background {
    background:transparent url('../images/am_bg_header.jpg') repeat-x 0 0;
    display: block;}

#header {
    height:107px;
}
```

On the iPad for some reason the background flows endless on the right but not on the left... the background_body tag is the outer most tag (except for body) however it still seems restricted on the right and I want it to go endless on the right.

And guess' why??

Comment: Are there any other styles on body_background? If you have something like "width: 100%" or anything defining that, that may be your issue.

Comment: no width... the prob only occurs in iPad... the html is pretty basic... body tag then div id="body_background tag... then content... close tags

Comment: Have you considered styling the body tag instead of a div?  I realize this may not be an option, given your design requirements, but it may help with your problem.

Comment: yes however we use leaderboards that sit above this div... wouldn't quite work the same if I just put a class in the body tag...

Comment: Have you tried positioning it in the center, ie "repeat-x center top;"

Comment: Show your markup or a live example and accept some answers.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is six months old, but I had the same problem and figured out the answer through the Safari Web Developer's Guide [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051): the default width of an iPad (or iPhone) viewport is 980px, if you design a page bigger than that, your automatic content (anything not given a width) seems to cut off at that edge.

To fix this, you need to set the viewport to the width you want your page to be viewed at by adding a meta tag to the head, like so:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1050" />
</head>
```

If your page is less than 980px wide, then this probably isn't the problem you are having.